# How to configure highlighting in Vim?

Tags: git, vim, msysgit, vim-syntax-highlighting

After upgrading Git for Windows I was surprised with the change in color scheme for Vim. Almost everything is highlighted in bold, so the text is "shouting" on me. For example committing in Git, the comments and subject string displayed in Vim are in bold, and that is very unpleasant.

While I could find a way to change the style for each separate type of text, that would be a lot of work to do. I'm looking for simpler ways to improve highlighting. Is there any single file (or a small number of files) that I could copy from the PC with old Git for Windows and good color scheme to the new one?

Comment: What colorscheme are you using? The default one hasn't changed (apart from adding highlight groups) in decades.

Comment: Are you sure it's the vim theme that changed (`:colorscheme`) and not the terminal's font settings?

Comment: @romainl, I'm using the default color scheme.

Comment: @DmitryKuzminov then you should follow Jay's hint.

Comment: @Jay, that is not a problem with fonts. I'm not sure whether the color scheme is part of Vim, Git or MSYS2, but overall it uses bold too much. That relates to the highlighting in Vim that displays commit message, `git log`, etc. Probably that is Git that overrode these settings.